How can I prevent my dishes from having sand in them after running through the dishwasher?
I have had this issue with three different dishwashers, so it is probably user error in some way. I want to know in what way so that I can correct the error.
It first happened when I tried to wash a thermos. When it was done, there was what looked like sand inside the thermos. But, it was just those three dishes so I moved on. Now, I have a large number of empty glass jelly containers that I want to reuse for drinking things. Sometimes there are only a few grains of sand and sometimes it's much more (a few square centimeters of the dish, usually near the corner of the bottom, are fully caked). Rarely, one comes out completely clean.
I suspect that this is due to the neck of these dishes being slightly (and it's very slight, like a single millimeter in the case of the jelly jars) narrower than the dish's main part's radius, or because they're deeper than most dishes so the water does not fully spray up and inside them.
To fix, I tried:

using the bottom rack
using a dishwasher cleaning product
multiple dishwashers
manually removing the shit and then rewashing
using better/different detergent
cleaning the filters
adding detergent outside the main detergent tub to use with pre-rinse

What can I do to correct this issue?

Have you measured the hardness of your water?  A picture of some of these items in the dishwasher just after the cycle being run might be informative.

Are you on well water?  It sounds more like a water problem.  Is it real sand or feels like sand?  What happens when you fill a glass with hot water and leave it sit?

It is municipal water. It looks like sand. It feels a bit softer than sand. It happened in three different residences too (hence the three different dishwashers) in the same city. I'll try leaving a glass of hot water out.

Are you putting these dishes up-side-down? I don't see how an up-side-down thermos or cup can accumulate anything in it. If you are putting them up-side-up (or they get flipped by the water) the sand/grit is probably the dishwashing soap that's not fully dissolved.

@EliIser Yes, I am putting them upside-down such that no water can accumulate in them

Are you pre-rinsing the food off the dishes?

Crip659 asks a great question above. Is the "sand" in the water from the municipal source (which would explain its presence in three difference residences), or is it purely local to your current house (which would suggest degrading pipe(s) between the meter and the house).

@EliIser I get powdery deposits in glasses etc in the corners of my top rack at times. A rotating spray arm in a rectangular space doesn't rinse the corners as well as other areas.

Having had similar issues, I'd say you're mainly doing the right thing but you should also:

Clean the machine by hand, filters, door seal etc., and check the filters for damage. Clean the sump under the filters as best you can, ideally emptying and refilling it.

Carefully check the spray arms to make sure all holes let water out. If they're removable, take them out and pour water into the opening. The holes in mine sometimes get blocked by oats that somehow got past the filter (probably when I take the filters out to clean them)

Check whether there are specific locations that are worse than others. The corners aren't good for narrow items because they don't get so thoroughly or vertically sprayed. That's where I have trouble so on the top, cereal bowls etc. Go in the corners, glasses in the middle of the sides. At the bottom, the best prongs for holding bottles aren't the best located.


Overall I believe the problem to be inadequate rinsing - the things that get this grit can come out dirtier than they went in. Even with all in one tablets, in a hard water area make sure the salt is topped up and use rinse aid, though it can be turned down.
An extra rinse might help if that's available on your machine, or a wash without a drying cycle, then either a rinse by hand or an extra cycle. But that's extra hassle and only worth it if nothing else works. The drying cycle seems to set the muck so it's harder to get off, requiring a soak then a scrub. A quick wash that finishes with a hot rinse and no drying cycle gives you the chance to check things, though of course it's not good for really greasy stuff.
Obviously scraping before putting dishes in is necessary, but hand rinsing doesn't seem to help with one exception: coffee grounds. If you get a lot of coffee grounds in the machine they collect in the same places as the grit you're seeing, and clog the filter which also makes for inefficient rinsing.
